# How do I find the number of items in a duplicate within a list in python?

Tags: python, list, function, duplicates

What I have already is a function that returns which numbers are duplicates like this:

```
X = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
def Dupe(l):
    return set([x for x in l if l.count(x) > 1])
print(Dupe(X))
```

which will return {1, 2}.
What I am looking to do is have a function like this:

```
X = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
def DupeL(l):
    (CODE HERE)
print(DupeL(X))
```

and that would return {3, 2} because there are three ones and two twos. Any ideas?

Comment: you can just write `set([1, 1, 1, 2, 2])` and it returns `{1,2}`.

Comment: for the second part search for `collections.Counter`

Answer (score 0):

You were going correct. But I would recommend you to create a dict which shows you the element as well as the number of times it is repeated. Iterate the set and check for occurences for each element of set in the list.  Just use `.count()` method to get the number of occurences in the list. Then add it to an empty dict which shows you the element and it's duplicates. Your code:

```
x=[1,1,1,2,2]
def Dupe(x):
    di={}
    c=set([v for v in x if x.count(v)>1])
    for i in c:
        di[i]=x.count(i)
    return di
print(Dupe(x))
```